# Getting a domain sub-directory url for a new server

Tags: redirects, url, subdomain, webserver, ip-address

I have an web application server running tomcat and i need to publish my APIs to internet users. However I don't have a domain name for this server and I can only put the ip address of this server (e.g. *145.XXX.XXX.XXX*) to point out where my API xml files are located.

I have another web server running with a domain name "*http://www.webserver.com*" registered on the internet and I want to make use of its domain name to server my web application server API xml files location. How can I do that? using "www.webserver.com/api" or using "api.webserver.com"? which is better?

Also I wonder if I want to publish a *"rstp://145.XXX.XXX.XXX"* web link for video streaming purpose, can I use *"rstp://www.webserver.com/api"* to replace it and how to do it? I always thought the url contain domain sub-directory name cannot point to another IP address, it only can point to another folder location on the webserver itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a subdirectory, since you'd only be able to do a redirect and that is not what you require. As you mention, a sub directory cannot *point* to another IP address.

However, you could perhaps use a subdomain, of the form `http://api.webserver.com` and set up a DNS "A" record for this subdomain in the webserver.com DNS zone that points to the alternative IP address. For example:

```
api.webserver.com. 14400 IN A 145.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Comment: Actually I thought the same way but I just need a bit confirmation on this. Looks like I have to convince my IT network team to give me a subdomain address then.